# Problem with running shell script using Python subprocess module on Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, linux, shell, raspberry-pi4

I am trying to run a security camera system on a raspberry pi using python. I have two scripts, one for monitoring and one for live streaming. I wrote a third script to switch between running the livestream and the monitoring code.

When I choose option 2, the live stream script runs correctly, but when I switch to option 1, the live stream script terminates but the run.sh script is not executed. Instead, I get two errors: sh: 0: Can't open /home/pi/Desktop/run.sh or cannot access '/home/pi/Desktop/run.sh': No such file or directory.

I am certain that the run.sh script is in the desktop and has the same name, and when I run it directly, the monitoring works correctly without any problems.

**Here is the code for the third script:
**

```
import subprocess
import time
import sys

def run_security_system():
    security_system = subprocess.Popen(["sh", "/home/pi/Desktop/run.sh"])
    return security_system


def run_live_stream():
    live_stream = subprocess.Popen(["python", "/home/pi/Desktop/live/server.py"])
    return live_stream

def terminate_process(process):
    process.terminate()

process = None
while True:
    user_input = int(input("Enter 1 for security system or 2 for live stream: "))
    if user_input == 1:
        if process:
            terminate_process(process)
        process = run_security_system()
    elif user_input == 2:
        time.sleep(2)
        if process:
            terminate_process(process)
        process = run_live_stream()
    else:
        print("Invalid input, try again.")
```

**run.sh
**

```
#!/bin/bash

source ~/env/bin/activate
cd ~/Desktop/Al-YamamaEyeALPHA
python main.py
```

I need help resolving the issue with running the run.sh script when I choose option 1.

I tried to run a shell script using subprocess in Python, but got errors "sh: 0: Can't open /home/pi/Desktop/run.sh" and "cannot access '/home/pi/Desktop/run.sh': No such file or directory". Expected the script to run, but it didn't work.

Comment: Could it be some permission issue, like the shell script permission are granted as execute only for root or at least another user than the one executing the selection script ?

Comment: It's not clear if shell code is involved here, but a good debugging technique, regardless of language is described in  the section "How to turn a bad script into a good question" in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info (Skip the version info at the top). Oftentimes, following this technique you will find the base of your problem and fix it by yourself. If you're still stuck, use your debugging version created with the above and turn it into an [mcve] . Good luck.

Comment: I checked the permission from the terminal using (ls -l /home/pi/Desktop/run.sh) I got ls: cannot access '/home/pi/Desktop/run.sh': No such file or directory

Comment: Try specifying the complete/absolute path.